# Application intent is not working from node.js to SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, cdc

I am trying to use application intent parameter while connecting to SQL Server from node.js code.

I tried to set below configuration .the connection is happening.but when I am executing some query (on `sys` tables like `sys.dm_cdc_log_scan_sessions`) from this node.js code, I can see I am getting the query result. But I am not supposed to see any result if I use `applicationintent = ReadOnly`.

```
let config = {
  connect: {
    server: <server-name>,
    authentication: {
      type: "default",
      options: {
        userName: <u-name>,
        password: <password>,
      },
    },
    options: {
      port: 1433,
      encrypt: true,
      trustServerCertificate: true,
      rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: true,
      database: <db-name>,
      ApplicationIntent: 'ReadOnly',
    },
  },
  port: 4000,
};

 let connection = new Connection(config.connect);
    connection.on("connect", (error) => {
      ..........
      }
```

Comment: `ApplicationIntent` is a connection string keyword. Since you're passing in a config object have you tried setting `options.readOnlyIntent: true`? Ref: [Connection API](https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html)

Comment: Which driver are you using?  Read-only routing requires functionality in the client driver.

Comment: I am using Tedious. Thank you very much @AlwaysLearning.It is working now. Thanks for sharing this.